# What may cause question marks instead of non-ASCII symbols?

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, pdo

Can't figure out why is it happening, there is definitely something wrong with the enviroment.
I have db declared as

```
CREATE DATABASE `mydb` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */
```

Then I have a table declared as

```
CREATE TABLE `myabstract_table` (
  `key_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `varchar_field` varchar(128) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`key_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Then I have usual for this case php code:

```
function execSQL($conn, $sql, $values = false) {
  try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    if ($values) 
      foreach($values as $param=>$value)
        $stmt->bindValue($param, $value);
      if ( ! $stmt->execute() ) {
        error_log ("PDO Error: ".json_encode($stmt->errorInfo()));
        return false;
      }
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
      error_log ("Exception: " . $e->getMessage());
      return false;
  }
  return $stmt;
}
```

and after that the strings are saving (via INSERT statement) to db with **question marks** instead of non-ASCII symbols

PS. I perform `set names 'utf8'` before any sql request, all php stuff is cofigured for UTF-8, html document header contains meta tag with UTF-8 secified as charset;
the only thing I didn't try is to change default charset of schema itself (it's currently latin1) since I'm pretty sure it's not at issue. Or is it?

[image]

Comment: Its all happening because of collation use `utf8_general_ci` everywhere.

Comment: @Yogesh Collation is not the same as *encoding*, and he's using `utf8` as encoding already!

Comment: Is your data actually encoded in UTF-8? See [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/).

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure the data is UTF-8, i did output to error_log $values array

Comment: Well, if all your data in utf-8, and you are running `set names utf8` after connect, there would be no question marks.

Comment: Which non-ASCII symbols are being saved as question marks? MySQL can handle conversion of UTF-8 characters that have a representation in Latin-1 (á, é, í, ó, ú, etc.).

Comment: How do you read your data back? The question mark is an Latin1 (8-bit) character interpreted as UTF8. Are you sure the data is **inserted** wrongly? Is the problem not when you get the data back? How does your data show when you do a raw `SELECT` from the command line?

Comment: Yes, I thought about it. I used standard mysqldump util and looked inside the dump. there were question marks too. so I'm pretty sure it's not an issue with displaying

Comment: @bob esponja - qustion marks are instead of russian symbols

Comment: Have you verified the actual encoding of your dump? Please check the result from the command line. "Pretty sure" is not sure enough, one must be absolutely sure.

Comment: Added piece of sql dump hex representation

Comment: Well, if you have ???s in your dump already, what you're asking from us? What magic is supposed to make some particular character out of a question mark?

Comment: The ??? in the dump could mean that the console is not able to display the characters. Connect to the server using a system that has the correct fonts and the right encoding, then view the records in the table.

Comment: I've produced that sql dump to make sure the issue is not in display values in web browser but that they really exsists as question marks in table. these values were inserted by my PDO based php code. I'm trying understand, why isn't working as I expect. why is it inserting ??? instead of legal utf8 symbols.

Comment: @Burhan Khalid I've made hex dump special for that purpose. As you can see all question marks have the same ASCII code (0x37 which is 100% **?**)

Comment: because you didn't run set names query before insert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've found the reason. There was another bit I forgot to mention. It's stored procedure. This procedure was inserting rows not usual INSERT right from php.

I think, default schema charset affects procedure IN varchars parameter declared without explicit charset. I've finally done the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_myabstract_proc`(
  `prm_key_id` int(10),
  `prm_varchar_param` varchar(512) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
)
BEGIN
-- some insert logic here
END;
```

(`CHARACTER SET utf8` option made the trick)
So in my case mysql engine was dealing with prm_varchar_param as with latin1 inherited from schema attribute.

Comment: So it looks like the database charset *did* mean something @YourCommonSense ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the character set of the database to UTF-8 or a character set for [Cyrillic characters](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-cyrillic-sets.html).

Latin-1 can't encode Cyrillic characters and that's why they're appearing as question marks in the database.

edit: I just saw you're declaring the table with UTF-8 character set, so I'm stumped.

Comment: The dataase charset means nothing.